# Setting .htaccess to reach not the file to directory

Tags: html, css, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have some  problems about htaccess files. I created a mobile version for my website. My main website is wordpress, and I created a responsive html website for mobile version of it and I have some problems about seeing the html website from phones. So I need to learn two things.

Let's say my mobile site is on http://www.example.com/mobile/index.html

1) How can i edit .htaccess file for just reaching the website using the address http://www.example.com/mobile without the index.html thing.

2) When I try my site with some simulators, it looks perfect but when i open the  example.com/mobile/index.html from my phone, it shows only pure html no css/js. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Hope i am clear enough.

Comment: lkyardimegitimiizmir.com/mobile/index.html is the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide link? If i'm understanding correctly:

1) Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/mobile%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

2) Links to your CSS and JS files are probably not correct - which is why you might be seeing just the raw HTML.

Comment: So did adding the edit I suggested in #1 work for the redirect? For item #2, page seems to be loading ok for me.

Comment: Actually i'm not looking for javascript redirection. What i need is doing it with .htaccess file.

Comment: Updated answer - try that.